# Kendo UI MVC, Grid View additional data using Data method not working

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Kendo grid in a razor view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PO>()
    .Name("manualMatchGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        BindFields(columns);
    })
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(l => l.Id);
        })
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("ReadInvoicePOs", "Invoice", new { invoiceID = ViewBag.InvoiceID })
            .Data("getInvoicePOsFilterData")
        )
    )
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
)
```

And the `getInvoicePOsFilterData` JavaScript function:

```
<script>
    function getInvoicePOsFilterData() {
        return {
            pONumber: $('#PONumber').val(),
            vendorId: $('#VendorId').val(),
            clientId: $('#ClientId').val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

When I look at the request in the Chrome Network Inspector, nothing is being sent for the data `InvoiceId`, which is the routeData.
[image: Chrome Network Inspector]

What am I missing?

Edit:

The controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult ReadInvoicePOs([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,
                                 int invoiceId, string pONumber, int? vendorId, int clientId)
{
    var pOs = dynamicPOManager.GetPOs(invoiceId, clientId, pONumber);

    DataSourceResult result = pOs.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Please post server side code as well..

Comment: I just did. But the problem is, It didn't even get to the ReadInvoicePOs Action because clientId is required.

Comment: only string types are allowed. in json request ..change your paramters types to string only..convert them later...that should work then

Comment: I actually put the random numbers as place holder, I read the values from controls using jQuery so I actually pass string. But I have figured out the problem. Take a look my answer. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was that `POST` is default for the `Read` method. I added "`Type(HttpVerbs.Get)`", and it worked just fine.

```
.Read(read => read
    .Action("ReadInvoicePOs", "Invoice", new { invoiceID = ViewBag.InvoiceID })
    .Data("getInvoicePOsFilterData")
    .Type(HttpVerbs.Get)
)
```

Comment: thats ok if its working....as for the record your read method should work for both GET and POST method because you did not define   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.GET)] or   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] tag on the top of the read method. so its accepting both verbs...strange it only works with GET

Comment: I actually did use [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]. I just forgot to copy that part. I see what you mean, That was definitely the problem because I have successfully used it in another application before.